# Problem with array - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I'm trying to do a Netflix clone using React but I've gotten this error and I'm not sure where the error is.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "./axios"
import "./Row.css"

const base_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/"

function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow }) {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
      setMovies(request.data.results);
      return request;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchUrl]);

  console.table(movies);

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <h2>{title}</h2>

      <div className="row__posters">
        {movies.map((movie) => (
          <img
            key={movie.id}
            className={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row__posterLarge"}`}
            src={`${base_url}${movie.poster_path}`}
            alt={movie.name}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Row
```

The error I keep getting is

[image]

Comment: `request.data.results` is undefined. We can't really tell you more than that without more debugging details.

Comment: Do some debugging.  1) Make sure `fetchUrl` is defined and is what you expect, 2) make sure the call that `fetchUrl` represents returns data that you are expecting.